# facing error Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type in mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am trying to download ftp file on my local drive. I amfacing following error

```
Message               : Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
```

I used batch processing. below is my flow.

Batch Processing Input flow http(One way) then in Processing record phase i used java component which is bind with my class. I wrote one function which will download my file from ftp server. My method is return void with no argument

```
     <batch:job name="filetosalesBatch1">
            <batch:input>
                <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8088" doc:name="HTTP" path="test"/>
<component doc:name="Java" class="com.ReadFile">
                <no-arguments-entry-point-resolver>
                    <include-entry-point method="ftpDownloadFile"/>
                </no-arguments-entry-point-resolver>
                </component>
            </batch:input>
            <batch:process-records>
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
```

below is my method

```
public void ftpDownloadFile()
{
  // logic for downloading file
}
```

When I eun my mule application got following error

```
Message               : Object "java.lang.String" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
```

How to solve this error please help me

Thanks

Comment: can any one help me please?

Comment: If you want to process records in batch you need to use Collections. The error said that your batch:input is returning String instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply I also tried with collection splitter but no effect.got same error

Answer (score 1):

Please try to replace your `ftpDownloadFile` method by this

```
public List<String> ftpDownloadFile() {
    return Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E","F","G");
}
```

What it is wrong in your flow? It is because the last payload is an String (request sent by http). In your method you should return a Collection and that would be the payload for the `batch:process-records`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a custom component for downloading a file. You can use the FTP component to retrieve the file contents and transform the content to a List so batch would able to process it.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I can not use ftp because it gives me error(host null) .Thats why i connect with ftp by custom component. Any other solution please?